# Does the existence of limit imply that the limit is exactly the function value?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives, continuity

If it holds, may I ask for a proof?

If it does not hold in general, may I ask for a counter-example?

Comment: Of course not. For example, imagine a function $0$ everywhere except at $1$, where it is $3$. Then of course it has a limit everywhere (zero) but at zero the function value is $3$, not equal to zero.

Answer (score 1):

No!

Consider the function defined by
$$ f(x) = \begin{cases} 0, &x\neq 0 \\ 1, &x = 0 \end{cases} $$
The limit of $f$ at $0$ is $0$, but the function's value is $1$.

In fact, functions which have the property that their value equals their limit are very special. They are called *continuous* functions and they play a very important role in mathematics.